# input field is not eeditable in mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I have made a simple form , you can check it on http://bspldev.review/phpmailer/ , using bootsrap its working fine on desktop but on mobile input field for name and email is not editable, that we can not write anything , only mobile field is working in mobile view, here is simple form code, i have give proper links for bootstrap and jquery library in header, here i will give excerpt of form only,

```
<form method="POST" name='' id="woohooEmail" action="">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label class="sr-only" for="fullname">Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" name="LastName">
   </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only" for="mobile">Mobile</label>
      <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
              +91
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mobile" name="Mobile"> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label class="sr-only" for="area">Email</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" name="Email"> 
   </div>
   <div class="pad">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="" class="btn btn-default btn-text ">
            Schedule
        </button>
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin" id="icon-load" style="font-size:24px; color:red; display:none"></i>
    </div>
<form>
```

Please check this on mobile and kindly suggest me some solutions

Comment: Did you get answer or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]In your mobile image is coming above the form, So increase your z-index of form's parent div or decrease z-index of your image in mobile screen using media query. You haven't add the div in above code so i just add z-index on form.Like :-

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

     #woohooEmail{
       z-index:9999;

}
```

or here you just can simply add z-index without media query too. it will work for every device

Comment: ok ,i'll make changes. but have you seen in mobile, can you fill the name field

Comment: yes i have done in my inspect. after that only i told the solution @ShahbazKhan

Comment: add z-index in div after container. just give that a class and then add z-index on that div.. i hope you get it. @ShahbazKhan

Comment: image is already below the code, after adding your code there is no change, my problem is not the position of image, its the input fields those are not working/editable in mobiles, can you suggest something about that

Comment: ya i just solved your problem only @ShahbazKhan . you have to add this property on div not form

Comment: @ShahbazKhan I also add a screenshot when m able to type in mobile screen . just check where i add z-index and do the same in your code too

Comment: sorry for late reply, you were right image was causing the error, but it did not work when you first gave the z-index value, later it is solved, as it is solving the problem, i will accept this as solution , but when you will see the img using its border still image is overlapping the form, one of my colleague solve this giving by using style="float: left ;" in img tag instead of z-index, any way thank you for your suggestion and help

Answer (score 0):

Build the form using boostrap's grid system. you can use one row spanning all the 12 columns and use the col-sm attribute

Comment: I have used the same, but unusual problem is ocuring in mobile view only